# Given Two 95% Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

Suppose we have given a two $95 \%$ confidence intervals for $X_1$ and $X_2$. They are normally distributed. From this how would we get a $95 \%$ confidence interval for $X_{1}/X_{2}$?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is this homework? If so, it should have the homework tag.

Comment: @PeterFlom: No it is not.

Comment: What do you mean by "$X_1$" and "$X_2$"? Usually a confidence interval is a statement about a *property* of a family of distributions, but (unless you are doing a Bayesian analysis with a prior) properties are not normally distributed--only the variables described by those distributions can be. If the $X_i$ are intended to designate random variables, then you need to specify what property you are estimating: the mean?  Variance?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can get the 95CI of mean(x1/x2) just by their separate 95CI.
Maybe you can do a simulation to get the empirical distribution of (x1/x2) if you also get the correlated relationship between x1 and x2